# Getting User input in a rectangular array, storing it and then counting

Tags: c#, arrays, input, foreach

So I've previously had a variable that was int competitors that would allow the user to input how many competitors joined a comp. I then have the user input the names based on how many.

I now want the user to input which category each competitor is in - e.g. If I'd had 5 competitors named say [0] Jake [1] John [2] James [3] Jonathan [4] Jimbo, how would i get them to ask for the user to assign say S to Jake, D to John etc, print that out?

I would then count how many people had each 'talent'

This is my code for the array section so far

Thanks

```
 string[] attendeenames = new string[competitors];
            for (int i = 0; i < competitors; i++)
            {
                WriteLine("Please input the names of competition participants");
                attendeenames[i] = ReadLine();
            }
            string[] talent = new string[3];
            {
                talent[0] = "S";
                talent[1] = "M";
                talent[2] = "D";
            }
```

After this i tried a read line - but I'm unsure if I should have done a foreach or a for loop and howto combine them

I can get user input into the first array but not getting user input that would assign for the second

Comment: Can't you ask for the talent inside the for loop alongside asking for the names?

Comment: "I would then count how many people had each 'talent'" I'd create a simple CLASS to hold both the name and their talent. Then use a `List<ClassNameHere>` to hold instances  instead of an array. Now you can use a simple LINQ query to group by talent and count how many of each there were. Look it up...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out - have only been doing it for a few weeks

Comment: I need to ensure that the responses for talent is limited to a certain number of answers so I'm assuming I need another loop for that

Comment: Are the talents limited to {S,M,D}?

Comment: Yeah, they're limited to S M and D and the limit for competitors are based on a previous input the user gives between 0-40

Comment: Thank you so much for the assist @Idle_Mind - it makes sense to use do and having the increment based on previous user inputs

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing more complex interaction with the user:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String response = "";
    string[] validTalents = { "S", "M", "D" };

    int competitors = -1;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("How many competitors? ");
        response = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(response, out competitors))
        {
            if (competitors < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number of Competitors must be greater than zero!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Response!");
        }
    } while (competitors < 1);
                
    string[] attendeenames = new string[competitors];
    string[] talents = new string[competitors];
    Console.WriteLine("Please input the names of competition participants.");
    for (int i = 1; i <= competitors; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.Write($"Name of Competitor {i} of {competitors}? ");
            response = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            if (response.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name cannot be blank!");
            }
        } while (response.Length == 0);
        attendeenames[i - 1] = response;

        int index = -1;
        do
        {
            Console.Write($"Talent of Competitor {i} of {competitors} [{attendeenames[i - 1]}] [{String.Join(", ", validTalents)}]? ");
            response = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToUpper();
            index = Array.IndexOf(validTalents, response);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Invalid Talent! Valid Talents are: {String.Join(", ", validTalents)}");
            }
        } while (index == -1);
        talents[i - 1] = response;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Sample run:

```
How many competitors? duck
Invalid Response!
How many competitors? 0
Number of Competitors must be greater than zero!
How many competitors? 3
Please input the names of competition participants.
Name of Competitor 1 of 3?
Name cannot be blank!
Name of Competitor 1 of 3? Bob
Talent of Competitor 1 of 3 [Bob] [S, M, D]? unicorn
Invalid Talent! Valid Talents are: S, M, D
Talent of Competitor 1 of 3 [Bob] [S, M, D]? s
Name of Competitor 2 of 3? Joe
Talent of Competitor 2 of 3 [Joe] [S, M, D]? M
Name of Competitor 3 of 3? Mary
Talent of Competitor 3 of 3 [Mary] [S, M, D]? d
Press Enter to Quit.
```