# add sex to passenger on buss program C#

Tags: c#

I just finished a programming 1 class and the last assignment I was making was named "the buss" where I was supposed to identify the different passengers on the buss. Sort the by age, count the average age on the buss and so on. But there were some things I didn't figure out in time and trying to do it now and was looking is someone could help me.

My problem is that I'm supposed to identify their sex and I just can't figure out how to make that.

The second one is to "poke them" and based on different age and sex make different comments.

```
 using System;
 using System.Globalization;
 using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
 using System.Security.Cryptography;

 namespace Bussen
 {
     class Buss
     {
         //passagerare means passenger
         public int[] passagerare = new int[25];
         public int antal_passagerare;
         public void Run()
         {
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
             Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the awesome Buss-simulator");

             int menu;
             do
              {
                 //the menu of every choise you can make.
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                 Console.WriteLine("Välj ett alternativ: ");
                 Console.WriteLine("1. Lägg till en passagerare. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("2. Kontrollera åldern på passagerarna. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("3. Beräkna den sammanlagda åldern på passagerarna. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("4. Beräkna medelåldern på passagerarna. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("5. Identifiera den äldsta passageraren. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("6. Hitta åldern. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("7. Sortera bussen efter ålder. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("8. Print sex. ");
                 Console.WriteLine("0. Avsluta programmet. ");
                 menu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                 switch (menu)
                 {
                     case 1:
                         add_passenger();
                         break;

                     case 2:
                         Print_buss();
                         break;

                     case 3:
                         Calc_total_age();
                         break;

                     case 4:
                         Calc_average_age();
                         break;

                     case 5:
                         Max_age();
                         break;

                     case 6:
                         Find_age();
                         break;

                     case 7:
                         Sort_buss();
                         break;

                     case 8:
                         Print_sex();
                         break;

                     case 0:
                         menu = 0;
                         break;

                 }
             } while (menu != 0);
         }
          //where you add you passengers by age 
         public void add_passenger() 
         {
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
             Console.WriteLine("Skriv in hur många passagerare ni vill lägga till.");
             string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
             int size = Convert.ToInt32(str1);
             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             {
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                 Console.WriteLine("Lägg till en passagerare genom att skriva in personens ålder ålder: ");
                 string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                 int nya_passagerare = Convert.ToInt32(answer);
                 passagerare[i] = nya_passagerare;
                 antal_passagerare++;
             }

         }
         // this is where you print out all the passengers.
         public void Print_buss()
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < antal_passagerare; i++)
             {
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                 Console.WriteLine("Passagerarnas ålder är: " + passagerare[i]);
             }

         }
         //this is where you add the total age on every passenger.
         public void Calc_total_age()
         {
             int sum = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length; i++)
             {
                 sum += passagerare[i];
             }
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
             Console.WriteLine("Den sammanlagda åldern på passagerarna är " + sum + ".");
         }
         //where you  calculate the average age on the buss
         public void Calc_average_age()
         {
             int sum = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < antal_passagerare; i++)
             {
                 sum += passagerare[i];
             }
             double dsum = Convert.ToDouble(sum);
             double dsum1 = dsum / antal_passagerare;
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
             Console.WriteLine("Passagerarnas medelålder är " + dsum1 + " år.");
             Console.WriteLine(" ");
         }
         //where you find the oldest passenger on the buss
         public void Max_age()
         {
             int maxAge = passagerare[0];
             foreach (var enPassagerare in passagerare)
                 if (enPassagerare > maxAge)
                     maxAge = enPassagerare;
             Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
             Console.WriteLine("Den äldsta passageraren är " + maxAge + " år gammal.");

         }

         //this where you find with seat the diffent passengers sitt on between surtn ages
         public void Find_age()
         {
             bool found = false;

             Console.WriteLine("Vilken är den yngst åldern som du vill hitta ?");
             int yngst = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

             Console.WriteLine("Vilken är det högst åldern som du vill hitta ?");
             int högst = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

             Console.WriteLine("Passagerarna som mellan åldern " + yngst + " - " + högst + " sitter i : ");

             for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length; i++)
             {
                 if (passagerare[i] > högst || passagerare[i] > yngst)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("stolen " + i);
                     found = true;
                 }
             }
             if(!found)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("OBS det finns inte sån ålder i bussen ");
             }
         }

         //this is where you sort the buss from ungest to oldest passenger
         public void Sort_buss()
         {
             int temp;

             for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length - 1; i++)
             {

                 for (int j = 0; j < passagerare.Length - 1 - i; j++)
                 {

                     if (passagerare[j] > passagerare[j + 1])
                     {

                         temp = passagerare[j];
                         passagerare[j] = passagerare[j + 1];
                         passagerare[j + 1] = temp;
                     }


                 }

             }
         
             for (int i = 0; i < passagerare.Length; i++)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Passagerare  " + (i + 1) + " är " + passagerare[i] + " år gammal  ");

             }

         }
         //this is where im supose to identify with sex every passenger has...
         public void Print_sex()
         {
             for (int k = 0; k < info.Length +1; k++)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("Plats" + info[k] + kön);

             }
         }



         class Program
         {
             public static void Main(string[] args)
             {
                 var minbuss = new Buss();
                 minbuss.Run();
                 var mysex = new sex();
                 Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                 Console.Write("press any key to continue . . . ");
                 Console.ReadKey(true);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Currently you are only storing the age of a passenger in `passagerare` (because of [Lägg till en passagerare genom att skriva in personens ålder ålder](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=L%C3%A4gg%20till%20en%20passagerare%20genom%20att%20skriva%20in%20personens%20%C3%A5lder%20%C3%A5lder%3A&op=translate). You should find a way to store more info on a passenger than just his age, when you want to store `sex`.   This might be covered in a next programming lesson?

Comment: Have you already learned how to write and use classes or structs? If yes, create a class or struct that represents one passenger and give it properties age and sex. Then use a list of that thing instead of your list of integers that just represents age.

Comment: I think Gender might be more applicable, Sex could indicate too much fun :)

Comment: You'd need another array to track Gender: `public String[] passagerGender = new String[25];` This is the approach you'd take at your level of experience. A more advanced approach would be to ENCAPSULATE all the related information into a CLASS.

Comment: ok. and how do i takes those genders to specific passengers? @Idle_Mind

Comment: The first passenger will have age which is stored in `passagerare[1]`, you can store sex in `passengerGender[1]`.

Comment: no this was a thing to criteria to get a A grading on this project and not something we needed to do, but i want to learn so thats why i want to do it @Luuk

Comment: See my [recent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74891342/2330053) that stores two pieces of information in two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like others have suggested, the best way to do this is to refactor (change) your code to use classes. This is called object oriented programming. I'll try my best to explain it for your current level of experience.

Firstly, create a class. Let's call this "Person".

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, let's create a list to hold the people on the bus. Instead of creating an array with a set size, we'll create a List.

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
```

Now, in your "add_passenger" method, which I advise you rename to follow the general [coding standards](https://www.dofactory.com/csharp-coding-standards), to "AddPassenger".

```
public void AddPassenger()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in hur många passagerare ni vill läggatill.");

    // Let's presume the input is in the format Name, Age, Sex.
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // This will create a string array with all the "details".
    // E.g [0] = Name, [1] = Age, Sex [2].
    string[] personDetails = input.Split(",");

    // Instantiate a person object and populate the properties.
    Person person = new Person();
    person.Name = personDetails[0].Trim();
    person.Age = Convert.ToInt32(personDetails[1].Trim());
    person.Sex = personDetails[2].Trim();

    // Add the newly created person to the people list.
    People.Add(person);
}
```

Now you're probably thinking that your bus can a very large amount of people, which is right because a List can hold a couple billion items - that's a pretty big bus! I would advise to add a method that checks the count is less than 25 before the AddPassenger() method call within your switch statement.

I would also like to advise that C# has an incredibly powerful ability to do searches within lists and can even perform mathematical calculations for you in one liners using something called LINQ. An example of this from your sample code would be your "Calc_total_age" method - which I would rename to CalculateTotalAge (it's better to be specific what a function does than to abbreviate. This helps other developers working on your code understand what it's doing if it's clear.

```
public void CalculateTotalAge()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

    // Calculate the total age using a LINQ expression.
    int totalAge = People.Sum(x => x.Age);

    Console.WriteLine($"Den sammanlagda åldern på passagerarna är {totalAge}");
}
```

Finally, to answer your question about listing the age of every person on the bus, we can do the following.

```
public void ListSexOfEveryPerson()
{
    foreach(Person person in people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name}'s sex is {person.Sex}");
    }
}
```

If we wanted to get creative and use LINQ expressions, we could do:

```
public void ListSexOfEveryPerson()
{
    people.ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name}'s sex is {p.Sex}"));
}
```

If LINQ expressions are confusing at this time, then just use the first example until you feel comfortable, there's nothing wrong with a foreach loop!

Also, if you're wondering what the '$' symbol before the quotation is used for, it's for [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). It's a better way of 'injecting' values into a string instead of doing "X" + "X" + "X".

Hope this helps!

Comment: wow! thank you. i will try this, im just a beginner in coding so i don´t know that much. i took this programmer 1 class so that i could take a more advance class in programming and learn more. thank you :)

Comment: im having some problem with your solution with the List. because i have "passagerare" and "antal_passagerare" and "passagere.Length" in my program im having some problem changing them to person/Person and vise versa, do you know what im doing wrong? @Owen

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry could you explain what the issue is you're facing? Is it possible for you to copy your code to https://pastebin.com/ for me so I can check it for you? It sounds like you need to remove the "public int[] passagerare = new int[25];" and change it to "List<Person> people = new List<Person>();" like in my example. The List type has a lot of extension methods and one of them is ".Count()" so you don't need to hold a count in the int you have named "antal_passagerare". If you wanted to find an average for example, you can use the LINQ expression "people.Average(x => x.Age);".

Comment: here is the what i tried last, i have more or less pasted the person/Person and people to where passagerare/Passagerare have been but it haven´t made the code work https://pastebin.com/qUdDuExe here if you could take a look and see what is wrong i would appreciate vary much :)

Comment: @KentKarlsson here you go. I've also updated my answer as I realised there was a typo in the code around the .Split() extension method. It was originally a "string" but was corrected to a string array "string[]" since .Split() returns a string array. Happy coding :) If this helps please consider marking my answer as the solution :) https://pastebin.com/EtvsM6jT

Comment: hi again. im having some problem again with the code that you changed and i cant add any passengers. when i try to add any i get the problem index was outside the bounds of the array... i know that the problem is that i cant add a value, but i don´t know how to make a a non specific value in a List array like i did in the int array... how do i do that?

Comment: @KentKarlsson if you changed it to a List array of a specific size, then you'll need to do a check before you add the passenger to make sure there is enough room. If the list/array is full, then don't proceed with adding a passenger otherwise you will get the error you're getting.

Comment: but i cant add any passengers... every time i try it says that the array in out of bounds.  @Owen